# How come $k$ dimensional manifold can not be $m$ dimensional manifold$(k \not = m)$?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I want to obtain contradiction...
Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. 
I managed to show on one hand $X$ is an $k$ dimensional manifold,
and then also that $X$ is an $m$ dimensional manifold, where $m \not = k$. Now I want to say this is not possible hence we have obtained contradiction.

Although I'm very sure this is the case, I wasn't sure how to show this 
(that $k$ dimensional manifold can not be $m$ dimensional manifold)...
Any comments on how to see this are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You should read the (deep) "Invariance of Domain Theorem".

Comment: If you're studying differential geometry, and are (presumably) dealing with only smooth manifolds, you don't need Invariance of Domain to show that different dimensional manifolds aren't diffeomorphic. Just note that the tangent space to a $k$-dim'l manifold is $\mathbb{R}^k$ and $\mathbb{R}^k \cong \mathbb{R}^m$ if and only if $k=m$.